# Problems using cin in C++

Tags: c++

So, I've just begun learning c++, and i've been watching some tutorials, etc. I wrote a small program that should act like a magic eight ball, however I'm having some troubles with the cin command. I've written cin >> x; where x is a string, and when the user types their question, the program is supposed to print a random response. Sounds simple enough, but if the user types more than 1 word in the question, more than 1 response is printed. So, if i type "Will I live to be 100?" I get 6 answers instead of 1. Here's my code: (I'm sure it's probably messy and not very well organized or coded in the most efficient way, like I said, I'm a beginner.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

string z = "Yes";
string b = "Signs point to yes";
string c = "It is certain";
string d = "It is decidedly so";
string e = "Without a doubt";
string f = "Yes, definitely";
string g = "You may rely on it";
string h = "As I see it yes";
string i = "Most likely";
string j = "Outlook good";
string k = "Reply hazy try again";
string l = "Ask again later";
string m = "Better not tell you now";
string n = "Cannot predict now";
string o = "Concentrate and ask again";
string p = "Don't count on it";
string q = "My reply is no";
string r = "My sources say no";
string s = "Outlook not so good";
string t = "Very doubtful";
string u;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    cout << "Ask A Question" << endl << endl << "Type 'Exit' to end the program" << endl <<           endl;
    int a = 1+(rand()% 20);
    cin >> u;

if (u == "Exit"){
    return 0;
}
if (u == "exit"){
    return 0;
}



if (a == 1){
    cout << z << endl << endl;
    main();
}
if (a == 2){
    cout << b << endl << endl;
    main();
}
if (a == 3){
    cout << c << endl << endl;
    main();
}
if (a == 4){
    cout << d << endl << endl;
    main();
}
if (a == 5){
    cout << e << endl << endl;
    main();
}
if (a == 6){
    cout << f << endl << endl;
    main();
}
if (a == 7){
    cout << g << endl << endl;
    main();
}
if (a == 8){
    cout << h << endl << endl;
    main();
}
if (a == 9){
    cout << i << endl << endl;
    main();
}
if (a == 10){
    cout << j << endl << endl;
    main();
}
if (a == 11){
    cout << k << endl << endl;
    main();
}
if (a == 12){
    cout << l << endl << endl;
    main();
}
if (a == 13){
    cout << m << endl << endl;
    main();
}
if (a == 14){
    cout << n << endl << endl;
    main();
}
if (a == 15){
    cout << o << endl << endl;
    main();
}
if (a == 16){
    cout << p << endl << endl;
    main();
}
if (a == 17){
    cout << q << endl << endl;
    main();
}
if (a == 18){
    cout << r << endl << endl;
    main();
}
if (a == 19){
    cout << s << endl << endl;
    main();
}
if (a == 20){
    cout << t << endl << endl;
    main();
}


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debugging information (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g` on Linux) and learn how to use the debugger (e.g. `gdb` on Linux).

Comment: consider to use arrays or `std::vector`

Comment: don't invoke `main()` within you program code

Comment: @SidSmith I suggest you read my answer as well because you are doing almost everything completely wrong. Even if you don't upvote/accept it, I advise you embrace my suggestions to improve your code drastically.

Comment: I certainly will, as I said, I'm a complete beginner. I'm always open to improvement, I just hadn't gotten to arrays, etc. yet. I was just trying to use some basic concepts I had learned, and I was frustrated on why it wasn't working. I've coded in other languages, so i'm familar with the concepts of recursive functions and whatnot, I just haven't learned the syntax for c++ yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `main()` over and over (recursively) in order to let the user ask another question. However, you don't take into account that `std::cin` stops extracting a string when it encounters a space, so you will end up making as many repetitions as there are whitespace-separated words in the user input.

---

Apart from this problem, the code is horrible. Sorry, it just is:

I. You declare 20 (or so) variables and a whole bunch of `if`s instead of an `std::vector<std::string>`. This will quickly become unmaintainable if you have more elements or if you don't know the number of items.

II. You are calling `main()` recursively, which is <s>legal but</s> illegal and **evil** and shows a **terribly bad programming style.** Just **don't do it.** Use a loop (iterations) instead.

III. You are `abusing namespace std;` which is also discouraged.

IV. You are also using global variables with no good reason.

All in all, you should rewrite your program so that it reads something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;

    v.push_back("Yes");
    v.push_back("Signs point to yes");
    v.push_back("It is certain");
    v.push_back("It is decidedly so");
    v.push_back("Without a doubt");
    v.push_back("Yes, definitely");
    v.push_back("You may rely on it");
    v.push_back("As I see it yes");
    // etc.

    char q[0x100] = { 0 };

    while (true) {
        std::srand(std::time(nullptr));
        int idx = rand() % v.size(); // this isn't perfect either, by the way

        std::cout << "Ask a question:" << std::endl;

        std::cin.getline(q, sizeof(q));
        if (std::string(q) == "exit")
            break;

        std::cout << v[idx] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And boom, it's just 37 lines instead of 128, and it's much readable.

Comment: He is a beginner, so maybe he does not know about containers yet.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just began c++, but I have coded in other languages so I'm familiar with the concepts of arrays, recursive functions, etc. I just haven't learned the syntax yet. Could you explain why it is not good to use "Using namespace std" though? What is the problem with doing that?

Comment: @SidSmith It can easily lead to name collision. When later you are developing multi-file projects with header files and includes, etc., and you throw in a few `using namespace std;`s, you'll eventually clutter the standard namespace.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you very much. I assume this goes for any other instances of "Using namespace x" I might encounter also?

Comment: @SidSmith Yes, it goes for all namespaces. Just leave poor `using namespace` alone for the time being :)

Comment: Are you sure about point number 2? Last I checked the standard says you are not allowed to call main from within your program. Or has that changed in a recent version of the standard?

Comment: @John5342 You are correct. "The function main shall not be used within a program.". This code is illegal (I mean the OP's one, not the one in the answer)

Comment: @John5432 Wait a bit, I have to check it. It's legal in one of `[C, C++]`, I always confuse which one it is.

Answer (score 4):

`cin` reads a string just till the space is reached so basicly `"Will I live to be 100?"` contains `6` strings.

In order to avoid your problem use `getline`

Also you should better change your 20 string variables to a single array or vector of strings.  In this case your `main()` will also look better as you will end up having just ONE `if` statemnt which will access an element of your array\vector depending on the random value.

Also you should move your global variables to `main()` and insert your code in a `while` loop which will have the following condition `while (cin >> u && u != "exit")` (leave only your variables declarations and `srand(time(0));` outside the loop)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17503076/2339141) answer shows how your program should actually look like.

Comment: It would be worth to point out the other problems in the code as well, we don't want to work with monkeys with gunz in there handz...

Comment: @H2CO3 I provided some ideas, mb a little different from what you have and added a link to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) to read a complete line

Answer (score 0):

The problem here, among arguably others, is that cin stops whenever it encounters a space, and your stdin has already buffered that entire question (line), so the next time you call cin actually it reads what you had in the stdin buffer.

You should consider using [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/) function, that reads until a line break/carriage return.

```
getline(cin,u);
```

You should also consider learning loops, to not call main() again, and arrays for better structuring your code.